# Unable to use HAML layouts with Middleman

Tags: ruby, layout, haml, erb, middleman

I've been having trouble switching from a default `layout.erb` file to an equivalent `layout.haml` file in Middleman. I want to use HAML for my layouts since I'm trying to become familiar with it, so I decided to replace the default layout with a HAML version. Unfortunately, when I replace `layout.erb` with `layout.haml`, I get this error:

```
NoMethodError at /
undefined method `force_encoding' for nil:NilClass

Ruby    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/tilt-1.4.1/lib/tilt/template.rb: in ensure in binary, line 289
Web GET localhost/

Traceback (innermost first)

/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/tilt-1.4.1/lib/tilt/template.rb: in ensure in binary
      string.force_encoding(original_encoding)...
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/tilt-1.4.1/lib/tilt/template.rb: in binary
      string.force_encoding(original_encoding)...
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/tilt-1.4.1/lib/tilt/template.rb: in extract_magic_comment
      binary script do...
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/tilt-1.4.1/lib/tilt/template.rb: in extract_encoding
      extract_magic_comment(script) || script.encoding...
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/tilt-1.4.1/lib/tilt/template.rb: in precompiled
        template_encoding = extract_encoding(template)...
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/tilt-1.4.1/lib/tilt/erb.rb: in precompiled
        source, offset = super...
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/tilt-1.4.1/lib/tilt/erb.rb: in precompiled
        source, offset = super...
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/tilt-1.4.1/lib/tilt/template.rb: in compile_template_method
      source, offset = precompiled(locals)...
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/tilt-1.4.1/lib/tilt/template.rb: in compiled_method
        compile_template_method(locals_keys)...
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/tilt-1.4.1/lib/tilt/template.rb: in evaluate
      method = compiled_method(locals.keys)...
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/tilt-1.4.1/lib/tilt/template.rb: in render
      evaluate scope, locals || {}, &block...
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/middleman-core-3.3.3/lib/middleman-core/core_extensions/rendering.rb: in render_individual_file
          content = template.render(context, locs, &block)...
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/middleman-core-3.3.3/lib/middleman-core/core_extensions/rendering.rb: in render_template
            content = render_individual_file(layout_path, locs, opts, context) { content }...
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/middleman-core-3.3.3/lib/middleman-core/sitemap/resource.rb: in block in render
          app.render_template(source_file, locs, opts, blocks)...
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/notifications.rb: in instrument
          yield payload if block_given?...
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/middleman-core-3.3.3/lib/middleman-core/util.rb: in instrument
        ::ActiveSupport::Notifications.instrument(suffixed_name, payload, &block)...
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/middleman-core-3.3.3/lib/middleman-core/application.rb: in instrument
    delegate :instrument, to: ::Middleman::Util...
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/middleman-core-3.3.3/lib/middleman-core/sitemap/resource.rb: in instrument
      delegate :logger, :instrument, to: :app...
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/middleman-core-3.3.3/lib/middleman-core/sitemap/resource.rb: in render
        instrument 'render.resource', path: relative_source, destination_path: destination_path  do...
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/middleman-core-3.3.3/lib/middleman-core/core_extensions/request.rb: in process_request
            output = resource.render do...
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/middleman-core-3.3.3/lib/middleman-core/core_extensions/request.rb: in block in call!
            process_request(env, req, res)...
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/middleman-core-3.3.3/lib/middleman-core/core_extensions/request.rb: in catch
          catch(:halt) do...
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/middleman-core-3.3.3/lib/middleman-core/core_extensions/request.rb: in call!
          catch(:halt) do...
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/middleman-core-3.3.3/lib/middleman-core/core_extensions/request.rb: in call
          dup.call!(env)...
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb: in call
      to_app.call(env)...
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/urlmap.rb: in block in call
        return app.call(env)...
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/urlmap.rb: in each
      @mapping.each do |host, location, match, app|...
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/urlmap.rb: in call
      @mapping.each do |host, location, match, app|...
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/showexceptions.rb: in call
      @app.call(env)...
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/head.rb: in call
    status, headers, body = @app.call(env)...
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/lint.rb: in _call
      status, headers, @body = @app.call(env)...
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/lint.rb: in call
      dup._call(env)...
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb: in call
      to_app.call(env)...
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb: in service
        status, headers, body = @app.call(env)...
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb: in service
      si.service(req, res)...
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb: in run
          server.service(req, res)...
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb: in block in start_thread
          block ? block.call(sock) : run(sock)
```

`layout.erb` looks like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <!-- Always force latest IE rendering engine or request Chrome Frame -->
    <meta content="IE=edge,chrome=1" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">

    <!-- Use title if it's in the page YAML frontmatter -->
    <title><%= current_page.data.title || "The Middleman" %></title>

    <%= stylesheet_link_tag "normalize" %>
    <!-- <%= stylesheet_link_tag "normalize", "all" %> -->
    <%= javascript_include_tag  "all" %>
  </head>

  <body class="<%= page_classes %>">
    <%= partial "header" %>
    <%= yield %>
    <%= partial "footer" %>
  </body>
</html>
```

`layout.haml` doesn't have quite the same content as `layout.erb`, but that doesn't seem to matter since it breaks no matter what:

```
!!!
%html
  %head
    %title
      = current_page.data.title || "The Middleman"
    = stylesheet_link_tag "normalize", "all"
    = javascript_include_tag "all"
  %body
    = partial "header"
    = yield
    = partial "footer"
```

At first I thought the error was only ocurring because the HAML itself was broken, but even a very simple HAML file that defines only doctype, html, head, title and body tags breaks. I then suspected that only ERb files were being taken as layout files - which I confirmed by renaming `layout.haml` to `layout.erb`, which didn't cause an error but just displayed raw HAML code instead. Even keeping `layout.erb` and making a sublayout `article_layout.haml` causes a similar error when navigating to a blog article, while making an `article_layout.erb` works fine.

So, I suspect that Middleman just won't accept anything except ERb for layout files. I can't find a single thing about this in the documentation, though, and I've even seen examples that all have `layout.haml` files that work perfectly fine. Is mine just different? Is there a flag I need to set with `middleman init` in order to use HAML files for layouts? What's going on?

Comment: I'm an idiot. I realized that I needed to restart the Middleman server whenever I change the layout file I'm using. `layout.haml`, `layout.html.haml`, etc. works fine when I restart it. Sorry about that!

Comment: Ouch, i an idiot too....

Comment: Lol same here, thanks!

Comment: nice to see mere humans here on stackoverflow

Comment: We should start a club.

Comment: Yeah, the idiots club. Thanks for this.

Answer (score 3):

As @r.pazyaquian mentioned in the sub-comments, if you change your layout file type, make sure to restart the server.